# KnockoutJS - table not updating when array is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0

I've created an example of the problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JustinN/qWeLT/1/

My actual code is hooked up to an ASP.NET web method, so the example code has been tweaked to point at a public web service to demonstrate.

Basically, I have an array which I bind to, however after an ajax call, the table does not show the updated information. I'm not sure what I am missing, I thought at first I needed the mapping plugin, so I've tried that but am still not getting anywhere.

Surely I'm not meant to applyBindings every time my data changes?

[EDIT]

JavaScript below:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
self.refresh = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.wipmania.com/json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d, self.items.address);
        }
    });
};
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.refresh();
});
```

HTML below:

```
<table data-bind="visible:items.length > 0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text:country"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:country_code"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I used to paste my code but then was asked for examples of JSFiddle all the time. I'll now include both. - Edited and fixed.

Comment: What for do you have the `.address` in this line? `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d, self.items.address);`

Comment: Good deal. Yeah, copy and paste is best (astonishing how often people retype -- and then introduce unrelated errors!) and live links as an *adjunct* (I prefer http://jsbin.com, but it's a matter of taste) are great.

Comment: What does `data.d` look like? (You can grab it from the network tab in whatever debugger you use and format it via http://jsonlint.com if you like, save doing it by hand.)

Comment: This might help : http://pastebin.com/AbzHXEML - I wish I could have made a public web service available to demonstrate the problem, rather than having to rely on mocking in JSFiddle, and displaying other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm7zH/1/

First of all I am using fake ajax data because of cross domain request. That's the data I got from your server. And using a setTimeout to simulate the async request.

Then you do a number of errors:

You try to map to property address of array, which does not exist. Second the address of your result is just a object, so I wrap it in an array to make it work.

Then you try to map to an existing observableArray, but supplying the array as the second argument, the second argument is the mapping options, the third is the correct place for that. I pass null as the mapping options in my example.

Lastly, for the table to be visible you say items.length > 0. What you want is items().length > 0 which is the length of the underlying array.

Comment: Thank you Martin for the corrected example and example, I have used that to correct my code and it's working beautifully now! My apologies to all for the terrible example I posted up with my initial question, I will try to submit clearer samples in future.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is `self.items`, but your ajax `success` call is updating `self.items.address`, which I'm guessing is `undefined`. So the mapping plug-in is creating a *new* model, unrelated to the original.

(You haven't shown what `data.d` looks like, but I'm assuming it's an array.)

> Surely I'm not meant to applyBindings every time my data changes?

Correct. You do that once, then updating the observables should (all being well) update the DOM.

Comment: It looks like my example which I whipped up to demonstrate my problem has a number of problems of it's own. The .address should be on data.d.address rather than on self.items - apologies for the confusion, however the problem is not there unfortunately.